# Why is a typedef not allowed in the inner struct?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, typedef

I have a program that defines a typedef struct within an existing typedef struct, and I am wondering why I am getting a compilation error.

Here is the program:

```
typedef struct Outer
{
    typedef struct Inner
    {
        int b;
    }INNER;


    INNER inner;
    int a; 

}OUTER;

int main()
{ 
    OUTER obj;
    obj.a = 10;
    obj.inner.b=8;
    return 0;
}
```

on compilation gives following error ::

```
test.c:3:5: error:expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘typedef’
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:17:5: error: ‘OUTER’ has no member named ‘a’
test.c:18:5: error: ‘OUTER’ has no member named ‘inner’
```

but, when I changed the program to

```
typedef struct Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        int b;
    };

    struct Inner inner;
    int a; 

 }OUTER;

 int main()
 {
    OUTER obj;
    obj.a = 10;
    obj.inner.b=8;
    return 0;
 }
```

it compiles successfully.

Why is typedef not allowed with inner structures?

Comment: Which compiler?  Which platform?

Comment: Because that's the standard?

Comment: You should be getting a compilation error on line 3 of the first example.  If you aren't, you're using a C++ compiler, but then a C++ compiler would accept the entire program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C does not allow a storage-class specifier (`typedef`, but also `static` or `extern`) in the declaration of a structure member. This is specified in the syntax of structures and unions declaration in 6.7.2.1p1 in C99.

```
/* The compiler will issue a diagnostic for this declaration */ 
struct s {    
    static int a;
};
```

You can compare 6.7.2.1p1  syntax with the syntax of a declaration where the declarator is not a function parameter or a structure / union member in 6.7p1 and see that in this case the storage-class specifiers are allowed.

Answer (score 6):

It's rather odd style to have a typedef inside a `struct` definition.

Normally the only things that should appear between the `{` and `}` of a `struct` definition are declarations of members of the structure.

As ouah says, a declaration within a `struct` definition cannot include a storage class specifier; the storage class specifiers are `typedef`, `extern`, `static`, `auto`, and `register` (and C11 adds `_Thread_local`).  This restriction makes sense because the storage for a struct member is determined entirely by the storage of the structure of which it's a member.

And `typedef` is a special case; it doesn't specify a storage class, but it's treated as a *storage class specifier* for syntactic convenience.

You *can* have other kinds of declarations inside a struct definition; for example, as you've seen, you can nest a struct declaration inside another.  For example, this program is valid (as far as I can tell):

```
struct outer {
    struct inner {
        int x;
    };                        // line 4
    struct inner foo;
};

int main(void) {
    struct outer obj;
    obj.foo.x = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

But gcc warns about the nested declaration:

```
c.c:4:6: warning: declaration does not declare anything [enabled by default]
```

(And before I tried this, I would have assumed it was illegal.)

**UPDATE** : `gcc -pedantic-errors` rejects this with a fatal error, suggesting it's illegal. I'll try to verify with the standard that this is illegal.

I think the best practice is to have *only* member declarations inside a struct. If you need to declare another type, declare it outside the struct declaration.  For example, I'd rewrite the code in the question like this:

```
typedef struct Inner
{
    int b;
} INNER;

typedef struct Outer
{
    INNER inner;
    int a;

} OUTER;

int main(void)
{
    OUTER obj;
    obj.a = 10;
    obj.inner.b=8;
    return 0;
}
```

(Actually, I'd write it like this:

```
struct inner {
    int b;
};

struct outer {
    struct inner inner;
    int a;
};

int main(void) {
    struct outer obj;
    obj.a = 10;
    obj.inner.b = 8;
    return 0;
}
```