# Declare an enum in a struct in objective-c using LLVM 5

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, enums, llvm

I am getting an error when declaring an enum inside a struct in an objective-c file. I've recently upgraded to LLVM 5 and didn't have this error before. I've tried C99 and C11. Any ideas whats wrong or is this illegal syntax that was permitted previously?

```
struct LogParams
{
    typedef NS_ENUM (int, Level)    // Error type name does not allow storage class to be specified
    {
        LevelTrace = 0,
        LevelDebug,
        LevelInfo,
        LevelWarn,
        LevelError,
        LevelFatal
    };

    uint64_t time;
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a typedef not allowed in the inner struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984418/why-is-a-typedef-not-allowed-in-the-inner-struct)

Comment: I think so as well. I must have been fooling myself when I thought it was permitted in an earlier compiler. I must have included it in an objective-c++ file where declaring a typedef in a struct is permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring an enum or typedef inside a struct is valid in C++ and Objective-C++ translations.

**It is not legal in C or Objective-C.**